# socketio client receiving duplicate messages

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm not sure if this is a socketio client or server issue but i'm receiving one plus message every time I navigate to the page and re-subscribe to the same room. I also emit a leave room every time I leave the page.

Backend:

```
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room){
        logger.info("subscribing to room", data.room);
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function(room){
        logger.info("unsubscribing to room");
        socket.leave(room);
    });

    socket.on('update', function(msg){
        io.sockets.to("room1").emit('udpate', msg);
    });
```

in my angular app I have this in my controller

```
function Controller(WebSocketService){
    var vm = this;

    function update(){
        WebSocketService.emit('update', "update message");
    }

    vm.WebSocketService.emit('subscribe', "room1");

    vm.WebSocketService.on('update', function(update){
        console.log("Update received");
    });

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        vm.WebSocketService.emit('unsubscribe', "room1");
    });

}
```

This works fine when I first navigate to the page. But when I navigate back to the main menu and then navigate back to this page with this controller and I send an update... On the backend I'm only seeing 1 socket message send but on the frontend I'm seeing "Update received" twice. Every time I navigate away and then back and fire my update function, I get that many duplicate messages.

I've checked the length of users in the room on the backend and it's just 1. Does my socketio client need to also unsubscribe somehow to the room?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors in console on client side? You don't have `vm.WebSocketService` also you don't have `$scope` in `Controller`.

Comment: Sorry, it's a stripped down version of the entire file - no, i dont have any errors and I do have scope. I'll update the op

Comment: It sounds like every time you enter the page you add another handler, which is why you get multiples. You need to clean up when you go, or at least check if the handler is already registered and not add another one

Comment: The socketio doc isn't very detailed, do you know how i can unregister a listener ont he client socket?